# Autosys R 12-Send alert only for consecutive failures

Tags: autosys

We are using Autosys for workload automation. We are getting alerts every time a job fails. These jobs run every 30 mins and failures usually get corrected in the next run of the job. Requirement is that we should get the alert only for consecutive failures of the job. In other words-there should be no alert first time a job fails. If this failure was to repeat we should get the alert. How can we achieve this? Is it even possible.

We tried setting the attribute alarm_if_fail to value 2. However, this attribute seems to accept only values 0 and 1 which corresponds to whether or not alarms are to be sent(for all failures).